# Drawing path between two markers Google Maps V2

Tags: google-maps, routes, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have two markers, namely `startLocation` and the other is `stopLocation`. startLocation will detect the user's current location, and then the user will walk, and when they stop they'll press stop and `stopLocation` will be captured as their new current location. I want to draw a polyline as the user is moving from the `startLocation` to `stopLocation`. 
Alternatively, the polyline can also be drawn after both markers for start and stop location has been created - whichever is more implementable. 
How can this be done? Most of the answers refer to retrieving routes and then drawing the polylines, but that's not what I want - I want to get the user's personalized route. In short, I want to record the route the user has taken. I've managed to create both markers already:

```
btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Create Start Marker
            // get current location
            LocationManager locManager;
            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

            Criteria c = new Criteria();
            c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            c.setBearingRequired(false);
            c.setCostAllowed(true);
            c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

            String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(c, true);
            Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            LatLng currentPosition = updateWithNewLocation(loc);

            Marker startLocation = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(currentPosition)
                    .title("Start Location")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 17));


        }

    });

    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Create Stop

            // get current location
            LocationManager locManager;
            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

            Criteria c = new Criteria();
            c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            c.setBearingRequired(false);
            c.setCostAllowed(true);
            c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

            String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(c, true);
            Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            LatLng currentPosition = updateWithNewLocation(loc);

            Marker stopLocation = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(currentPosition)
                    .title("Stop Location")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 17));

            // Draw dynamic line
        }

    });
```

Now all I need is to draw the line between the two markers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this without tracking the user's location. You should use the [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) function to listen and get the update of your user's location. Refer to [the developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#StartListening) for more information on listening to the GPS location.

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
// Or, use GPS location data:
// String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You might also want to use the snap to road function in the [newly released Google Maps Road API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap), to fix your raw lat/lng from GPS, and get a smoother path on the road. It does not currently have Android APIs, so you might need to use the Web API to access the snap to road service.

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=-35.27801,149.12958|-35.28032,149.12907|-35.28099,149.12929|-35.28144,149.12984|-35.28194,149.13003|-35.28282,149.12956|-35.28302,149.12881|-35.28473,149.12836
        &interpolate=true
        &key=API_KEY
```

After users stopped tracking or reached the end point, you can [create a polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polylines) based on their path.

```
// Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Let me know if it is not clear, and hope it helps.

Comment: Hey I'll try this out first! Thank you soo much :-) Really appreciate it!